# Access Javascript function variable in spree view

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, spree

```
<div class="row">
    <div id="product-container">
      <% pixel = access() %>
   </div>
</div>

<script>
 function access()
{
  return window.devicePixelRatio;
}
</script>
```

I am new in spree, i want to write javascript function which return something that value i needs to access in spree rails view(partial).Is there any way to execute above function without AJAX

Comment: It is not possible to execute a javascript function like this.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no. 
These tags:

```
<% pixel = access() %>
```

are for embedding Ruby code, and will not work with Javascript.
You would have to call the access function from inside of a  tag to make it work.

If you're looking for strictly visual changes, you can use Javascript inside of the  tag, but if you want to interact with the Spree API you'll have to use AJAX. It's really quite convenient to use, and there are plenty of examples of how to access it in the Spree docs: https://guides.spreecommerce.com/api/